# Ohm list and unique not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ohm

Documentation says Ohm lists are treated just like a Ruby array, but I see the following issues:

`MyModel.new` in rails console produces:

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`

That's on a line where I have `list :foo` where foo should be an array of integers.

Then, to follow up, I wanted to create a unique index on `attribute :bar` and I get the following when I comment out the list method and add unique:

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `unique' for MyModel:Class ``

Here's the class:

```
class MyModel < Ohm::Model
  attribute :email
  list :foo
  unique :email
end
```

This entire thing breaks down unless I comment out both the list and unique directives.

Comment: All the examples of `list` I've seen in the Ohm documentation have two parameters. See http://ohm.keyvalue.org/examples/philosophy.html

Comment: Then what's the issue with unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `assert_unique`?

```
class MyModel < Ohm::Model
  attribute :email
  index :email

  def validate
    assert_unique :email
  end
end
```